# How to write Confidential/SGX apps with Golang?

Tags: cloud, sgx, confidential

I would like to develop and deploy my Go microservices as SGX-/Confidential Computing app. What are the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Writing Confidential Computing Apps with Go requires two things:

**1. A Go runtime that runs inside the Confidential/SGX enclave**

Two approaches exist here:

Generic  LibraryOS (the intermediate between process- and vm-based enclaves)

- Graphene: https://grapheneproject.io/ (Not supporting Go yet)
- Occlum: https://occlum.io/
- LKL: https://github.com/lsds/sgx-lkl

Go SDKs and runtimes: While several runtimes for SGX exists to my knowledge only EGo supports Go.

- EGo: https://github.com/edgelesssys/ego

**2. An SGX API for Go (for remote attestation, sealing, etc. directly from Go)**

The LibraryOS's have their own API and might support Go bindings in the future, but when writing this you'd still need to write your own Go bindings in C/C++.

The ertgolib that goes together with the ertruntime provides a fully functional API layer that exposes most of the OpenEnclave/SGX functionalities directly to Go

- ertgolib: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/edgelesssys/ertgolib